# Как искать вопросы с определенными метками?

Tags: поддержка, faq

- Как осуществлять поиск вопросов, имеющих определенные метки?
- Как искать вопросы, имеющие определенные метки и содержащие определенный текст?

> Более подробно о поиске см. «[Как выполнять поиск?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)» в [Help-центре](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help).

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[How do I search for questions with specific tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5229/274323)».</sub>

Answer (score 5):

### Как осуществлять поиск по нескольким меткам?

Существует два основных способа поиска вопросов с определенными метками:

#### Поле ввода поисковой фразы

В поле ввода поисковой фразы введите интересующую вас метку в квадратных скобках. Вы можете искать вопросы отмеченные сразу несколькими метками и содержащие определенные фразы.

Простой пример поисковой строки:

> [python] [django] панель администратора

Здесь производится поиск фразы «панель администратора» среди множества вопросов, имеющих метки [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) и [django](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django).

Если вы производите поиск фразы, который является также и меткой, или фразы, содержащей общие с меткой слова, возможно, вам будет необходимо экранировать текст поискового запроса – для этого нужно заключить его в двойные кавычки.

#### Строка ввода адреса сайта

Вы можете производить поиск по меткам в адресной строке в следующем формате:

> [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/C# java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23%20java)

Этот способ является более мощным, так как вы можете использовать такие операторы как `or` или `not`. По умолчанию, для поиска в адресной строке действует оператор `and`.

Для поиска вопросов отмечанных одной или другой меткой (`or`):

> tagged/яблоки or апельсины

Для поиска вопросов отмеченных одной меткой, но не отмеченных другой меткой (`not`):

> tagged/яблоки -апельсины

Учтите, что поиск [не может начинаться](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46060/tag-search-not-operator-is-broken/49962#49962) с оператора `not`: в подобном случае из условий поиска этот оператор будет исключен.

Для поиска вопросов с метками по шаблону, используйте символ тильды:

> tagged/java~

Вы можете сочетать указанные выше варианты по своему усмотрению.