# Следует ли включать метки в заголовок вопроса?

Tags: поддержка, faq

Встречаются вопросы, при правке которых из заголовков были удалены названия языков программирования или технологий.

Разве поисковики – и люди, *использующие* поисковики – не выиграли бы от присутствия подобных меток в заголовках вопросов?

---

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/274323)».</sub>

Answer (score 11):

Stack Overflow имеет внушительную [систему меток](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean), что позволяет участникам понимать, о какой технологии идет речь в том или ином вопросе,  [просматривать или пропускать определенные темы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3450/), сужать [и конкретизировать поиск](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3407/) и даже [изучать темы, обозначенные метками, по соответствующим им разделам wiki](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/527/).

Система меток проекта *работает*: на нее можно смело положиться, если вам нужно *оповестить участников, заинтересованных в вопросах по метке в вашем вопросе*. Stack Overflow сделан таким образом, что *метки индексируются поисковиками* – так же, как и «тело» вопроса. Пользователи *гарантировано увидят ваши метки* и учтут их при ответе на ваш вопрос.

**Поэтому специально включать метки в заголовок вопроса не следует**

При написании заголовка вопроса *НЕ* рекомендуется использовать следующие форматы:

- [метка]: [заголовок вопроса]
- [заголовок вопроса] -- [метка] [метка] [метка]
- [заголовок вопроса] в [метка]
- [метка] [метка] [заголовок вопроса] [метка] [метка] [метка]
- [метка] [метка] [метка] [метка] [метка] [метка] [метка] [метка]

Единственный вариант, при котором использование меток оправдано – когда *они органично вписываются в формулировку заголовка*. Например,

> JavaScript, jQuery: когда использовать первый, а когда второй?

В данном примере метки используются принудительно, чтобы сгладить откровенно плохую формулировку. Заголовок было бы гораздо легче понять, если бы он выглядел следующим образом:

> Я могу воспользоваться jQuery, чтобы сделать горизонтальное меню, либо все-таки использовать простой JavaScript?

Следует также учитывать, что система автоматически поставит перед заголовком самую релевантную метку (если эта метка отсутствует в заголовке), чтобы облегчить поисковикам задачу по индексированию вопроса.

Comment: `Я могу воспользоваться jQuery, чтобы сложить два числа, либо всё-таки придётся использовать простой JavaScript?` =)

Comment: Мой личный вкус не видит ничего плохого в первом формате ([метка]: [заголовок вопроса]) - часто оказывается весьма удобным, а вот использования всех остальных однозначно следует избегать.