# JavaScript и JS - дублирование синонима метки в заголоке

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Посчитал излишним дублирование метки (хоть и с другим написанием) в заголовке воспроса:

[Получить 20 случайных чисел от 1 до 1000, но чтобы эти числа не повторялись](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624726/js-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-20-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%BE%D1%82-1-%D0%B4%D0%BE-1000-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)

Однако встретил неодобрение. Поскольку я не считаю себя  вправе решать это единолично, решил спросить.

**Доводы чтобы оставить:**

1. Для людей, которые как автор вопроса используют `JS`, а не `javascript` (Вопросы должны использовать ту терминологию, которую используют люди с подобным вопросом. Поэтому дубликаты не удаляются: люди могут задать один и тот же вопрос используя разные слова).
2. "`javascript`" (буквальная строка) не равна "`JS`" . Если в поисковик вбить "`JS что-то`", то автоматически не обязан найтись "`JavaScript что-то`" вопрос, поэтому следует оставить `JS`, чтобы облегчить поиск для людей, которые эту терминологию используют. Например, поиск SO не умеет искать по синонимам.

**Доводы за удаление:**

1. [Следует ли включать метки в заголовок вопроса?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3480/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0/)
2. В поисковых системах JS и JavaScript [синонимичны](https://www.google.ru/webhp?q=js#newwindow=1&safe=off&q=js)
3. Стандартизация. Если мы выпиливаем метки из заголовков, то это надо делать везде.
4. Повышение сложности правил. Нужно дополнительно определять, какие синонимы еще надо писать, и информировать об этом сообщество

Comment: @jfs родной поиск SO не умеет синонимизировать JS, JavaScript, Java Script, "JavaScript-у" и "JavaScript-е" - но это не повод вписывать всевозможные формы в заголовок каждого вопроса по JS

Comment: @PashaPash "оставлять" и "вписывать" это разные вещи. Без обсуждения свои правила вводить не хорошо.

Comment: @jfs как раз обсуждение о том, что метки надо убирать было: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles а вот обсуждения, что у этого должны быть какие-то исключения — нет

Comment: @jfs в этом случае - не было никакой разницы. [Автор просто вписывает технологию в заголовки своих вопросов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/193411/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9?tab=questions&sort=newest): [Как по клику запустить php файл из java и получить результат работы php](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545301/), [jquery Как получить id div-ва](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/555184/). Он делает это не ради соблюдения терминологии и не ради "повышения доступности". И к тому же называет JavaScript "Java".

Comment: @jfs чисто технически - у вопроса была текущая ревизия, полностью отвечающая правилам сайта, без технологий в заголовке. Вы пришли и вписали в заголовок JS, обосновывая это (1) доступностью для поиска (2) какой-то волей оригинального автора - якобы, тот придерживается именно терминологии JS. Т.е. ввели какое-то хитрое правило "когда сокращение от названия языка должн быть в заголовке", без обсуждений. По (2) - по вопросам видно, что автор до раньше вписывал JavaScript, но в этот раз ему было просто лень печатать полное название языка. По (1) - придется вписать JS во все существующие вопросы.

Comment: @Crantisz: к вам у меня никаких претензий--вы всё правильно сделали.

Comment: @Crantisz под "правильно" я имею ввиду: вы начали обсуждение на Мете, намеренно не  исказили позицию, с которой не согласны (такую бы интеллектуальную честность хотелось бы  у многих увидеть), даже если вы не видите разницу между правилами, применимыми к самой метке, и правилами, применимыми к **синонимам** меток, определённым на внешних поисковиках. Против **расширения** существующего правила, если явно принять во внимание, что даёт это расширение, какие есть недостатки (плюсы/минусы)—нет возражений.

Comment: @jfs полностью согласен - перед тем, как частично откатывать чужую правку, вам стоило бы начать обсуждение на мете. А не вводить свои правила. Например я  - пришел в вопрос из обсуждения на мете, в котором был достаточно заплюсованный ответ (решение сообщества?). Увидел, что автор спорной правки (вы) решил обсуждение на мете не создавать, а просто ввел свое правило "стоит оставлять синонимы меток в заголовках", тут же применил его, и вместо обсуждения на мете ограничился комментарием под вопросом. Я и применил решение сообщества и пошел дальше. Не знаю, к кому у вас могут быть претензии :(

Answer (score 8):

Я беспощадно выпиливаю и остальных призываю.
Тут для этого есть метки.

1. Даже, наверное, полные нубы понимают что `JS` и `JavaScript` - одно и то же.
   Это не `ECMA-262`, про которую не знают.
2. Сразу нивелируется тем, что любой поисковик, тем более гугл/остальные гиганты, понимает что это синонимы.

Однако, не стоит править только из-за заголовка. Всё не перевыправишь.

Comment: JavaScript (Oracle, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/816-6408-10/) и JScript (Microsoft, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbxc2t98(v=vs.85).aspx) - гарантированно НЕ одно и то же... почему Вы считаете, что JS эквивалентно именно первому?

Comment: @Akina следовательно, это еще один довод использовать метку `JavaScript`, и не писать `JS`

Comment: @Akina, если используется поделка от мелкомягких, то это обязательно в метки выносится. Думаю поисковики уже догадались ценить метки выше, чем заголовки. В тайтле нужно определить проблему, а не подробности (где, как, почему, в какой версии, etc.).