# Нормально ли, что метки не учитываются в поиске?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, метки, поиск

Во мне тут вдруг проснулся внутренний сеошник, и мне приспичило поискать свои вопросы по поиску.

Вбиваю «python icc», и — ничего:

[image]

Хотя я ожидал увидеть в результатах [этот свой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749575). Как видите, метка `python` там имеется.

Конечно, если поискать вопрос с явно указанной меткой «[python] icc», то всё успешно ищется:

[image]

Но мне что-то кажется, что сидеть угадывать, что нужно запихивать в квадратные скобки, а что не нужно, дико неудобно.

Есть ли какая-то причина, почему метки не ищутся вместе с обычным текстом? Или это просто недоработка поиска?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как искать вопросы с определенными метками?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3407/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Comment: В квадратных скобках указываются метки. А поиск по тексту на SE хреновый. Лучше в гугле искать.

Comment: @Suvitruf нет, я не хочу искать вопросы с метками. А вдруг метки `python` там не стояло бы, а стояла бы, например, `python-3.x`? И всё, по запросу «[python] icc» ничего не нашлось бы. Я хочу, чтобы по запросу «python icc» мой вопрос находился — именно так, без явного упоминания меток. // Вот про хреновость поиска как раз мой вопрос :)

Comment: Ищите через гугл https://www.google.com/search?q=ru+stackoverflow+python+icc&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 (:

Comment: Небольшой хак: используйте `*`, например: [`*python icc`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=*python+icc) или даже так: [`*python* *icc*`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=*python*+*icc*)

Comment: @АндрейNOP прикольно, но вот каждому пользователю, который недолго думая захочет поискать «python icc», об этом не расскажешь (как и про метки в квадратных скобках)

Comment: Ну справка по поиску есть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching но как звездочка работает там совсем мало объясняется. Я вот чисто случайно обнаружил, особенно если искомое слово находится внутри блока `код`, очень часто обычный поиск не находит там ничего, а со звездочкой срабатывает